# How to select all objects that are foreign keyed from another model in django?

Tags: python, django

Sorry for title, I do not know how else to express myself.

For example, I have this three models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Teacher(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    subject = models.CharField()

class Student(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    grade = models.CharField()
```

How can I select all **Person** models that are **Teachers**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Person.objects.filter(teacher__isnull=False) 
# return Person who has a teacher pointing to it
```